# Unmarshalling a processing instruction in Go using encoding/xml

Tags: xml, go, parsing

I have an XML file (MusicXML produced by Guitar Pro 7.0) and it contains embedded processing instructions beyond the usual `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` scattered throughout the file. I am trying to parse this into a hierarchy of Go `struct` types using `xml.Unmarshal(...)` with tags on my struct fields.

The MusicXML has processing instructions of the form `<?GP ... ?>` which I would like to retain so that when I write the XML back out, it will be accepted by Guitar Pro.

I cannot figure out how to unmarshall the processing instructions.

I have tried including a field with type `xml.ProcInst` and even tried tagging it as `xml:",innerxml"`, but that did not work.

I briefly looked through the unmarshall source code in the Go `encoding/xml` library, but did not see any special tags values that might help (and the documentation doesn't have anything either).

**Clarification:** Please note that the element that contains the processing instruction sometimes also contains other elements that must be parsed:

```
<staff-details number="1">
    <?GP 
    <root>
    <staff-tuning line="1">
    <tuning-step>G</tuning-step>
    <tuning-octave>3</tuning-octave>
    </staff-tuning>
    <staff-tuning line="2">
    <tuning-step>C</tuning-step>
    <tuning-octave>4</tuning-octave>
    </staff-tuning>
    <staff-tuning line="3">
    <tuning-step>E</tuning-step>
    <tuning-octave>4</tuning-octave>
    </staff-tuning>
    <staff-tuning line="4">
    <tuning-step>A</tuning-step>
    <tuning-octave>4</tuning-octave>
    </staff-tuning>
    </root>
    ?>
</staff-details>

<staff-details number="2">
 <staff-lines>4</staff-lines>
 <staff-tuning line="1">
  <tuning-step>G</tuning-step>
  <tuning-octave>3</tuning-octave>
 </staff-tuning>
 <staff-tuning line="2">
  <tuning-step>C</tuning-step>
  <tuning-octave>4</tuning-octave>
 </staff-tuning>
 <staff-tuning line="3">
  <tuning-step>E</tuning-step>
  <tuning-octave>4</tuning-octave>
 </staff-tuning>
 <staff-tuning line="4">
  <tuning-step>A</tuning-step>
  <tuning-octave>4</tuning-octave>
 </staff-tuning>
</staff-details>
```

Comment: Use `,innerxml` on the processing instruction's parent: https://go.dev/play/p/4HUe-e-GIAt

Comment: That's capturing the processing instruction, but none of the other fields inside the element (see clarification).

Comment: I think you'll have to implement a custom marshaler and unmarshaler. For example you could do something like this: https://go.dev/play/p/So7maNlO2M9 I know it doesn't look very neat but it's the best I could come up with.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll take a look at it. I started to play around with custom code, was hoping for an alternative.